# How to make multiple Strings equal to one value (Java)

Tags: java, string, initializing

I want something like this:

```
String Aa, Eb, Cc, Dd, Be, Ff = "1";
String Ba, Db, Ac, Ed, Fe, Cf = "2";
String Ea, Cb, Bc, Fd, Ae, Df = "3";
String Da, Ab, Fc, Bd, Ce, Ef = "4";
String Fa, Bb, Ec, Cd, De, Af = "5";
String Ca, Fb, Dc, Ad, Ee, Bf = "6";
```

But that doesn't work, It makes the last ones (Ff, Cf, Df, Ef, Af, and Bf), but the ones before that get ignored. Also, I don't want to make an array because the challenge (I'm in a class) was to program sudoku without using any forms of arrays.

Comment: You have to do `String Aa = "1", Eb = "1"` etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to initialize **each** String, like this:

```
String Aa = "1", Eb = "1", Cc = "1", Dd = "1", Be = "1", Ff = "1";
...
```

An alternative would be this:

```
String Aa, Eb, Cc, Dd, Be, Ff;
Aa = Eb = Cc = Dd = Be = Ff = "1";
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Arrays are not valid for you,

so you can

Do like

```
String Aa = "1", Eb = "1"....;
```

or

```
String Aa = "1";
String Eb = "1";
...
```

much more flexible than that is not defined in the java language